# JavaScript alert box with confirm on button press

Tags: javascript, alert

I have this link:

`<p id="accept-favor"><a title="Accept this Favor" href="?wp_accept_favor=<?php comment_ID(); ?>">Accept this Favor</a></p>`

I want to show a JavaScript alert box when a user clicks it saying: "Are you sure you would like to accept this reply as your favor?" with two buttons one saying "Yes" which will allow the function to run and the other saying "No" which will just cancel the postback and keep the user on the page.

How would I do this? Thanks :)

Comment: `onclick="return confirm(this.innerText+'?');"`

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can easily do it with a confirm onclick:

```
<p id="accept-favor"><a title="Accept this Favor" 
  href="?wp_accept_favor=<?php comment_ID(); ?>" 
  onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you would like to accept this reply as your favor?');"
  >Accept this Favor</a></p>
```

Though this will say OK/Cancel instead of Yes/No.  If you really want Yes/No, you'll have to use a custom dialog.

Comment: You're missing a closing bracket. The onClick code should be `onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you would like to accept this reply as your favor?');"`

Answer (score 24):

You can write `onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');"`.

The [`confirm` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.confirm) shows an OK / Cancel dialog and returns `true` if the user clicked OK.
`return`ing `false` from an `onclick` handler will cancel the default action of the click.

Answer (score 17):

You can use this function:

```
myFunction() {
     var x;
     if (confirm("Are you sure?") == true) {
         x = "You pressed OK!";
     } else {
         x = "You pressed Cancel!";
     }
     return x; 
}
myFunction();
```

Answer (score 6):

As other answers talk about direct *onclick*, I would like to present a solution for a "nicer" (IMO=in my opinion) version using the `addEventListener` and `preventDefault` methods. Because this way you could bind more *click* handlers.

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" id="confirmClickActionElementId">click me</a>
```

**JavaScript**

```
document
    .getElementById("confirmClickActionElementId")
    .addEventListener("click", function( e ){ //e => event
        if( ! confirm("Do you really want to do this?") ){
            e.preventDefault(); // ! => don't want to do this
        } else {
            //want to do this! => maybe do something about it?
            alert('Ok, lets do this!');
        }
    });
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ouyf86ya/

...or the old "`return`" way:

```
document
    .getElementById("confirmClickActionElementId")
    .addEventListener("click", function(  ){ 
        return confirm("Do you really want to do this?") ;
    });
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y2jLpkbb/