# Checking OK button is clicked on alert box

Tags: javascript

This the code for alerting some value:

```
alert('Click the OK button Now !');
```

So now i want to check whether the OK button is clicked or not.

How can I do this using this JavaScript?

Comment: you could use confirm instead of alert...?

Comment: I do not think you can do that with alert.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript alert box with confirm on button press](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952459/javascript-alert-box-with-confirm-on-button-press)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Confirm could work:

```
var r=confirm("Click the OK button now!");
if (r==true)
{
  alert("You pressed OK!");
}
else
{
  alert("You pressed Cancel!");
}
```

**Confirm HAS to have an OK and Cancel button**. If you only want one button, you should either use the `alert()` method (which doesn't tell you if the `OK` was clicked) or you should look into something like the [jQueryUI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) control.

The jQueryUI dialog is a bit more complicated because you need to include some extra JavaScript libraries and do a bit of extra wiring up to get it to work. There are a lot of examples to follow [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).

Comment: @KichuUser just add parenthesis `if (confirm('...'))`

Comment: Sorry about that. I fixed it, I had a small typo in it.

Comment: OK got it,but i have one doubt if there is any code to change the OK/Cancel button to single OK button of confirm box?

Comment: Not with `confirm`. It has to have both OK and Cancel. And `alert` doesn't return a value telling you that the `OK` was clicked. If you must have a single OK button and you need to act on the OK button, then you should look into the JQueryUI dialog box.

Comment: So you mean that there is no way to single OK button without JQuery UI?

Comment: Yes, JavaScript alone won't allow for what you want.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10151/discussion-between-kichu-user-and-paul-oliver)

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you might want a confirm box instead of an alert:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp

This returns true or false depending on what the user presses. Alert does not return a value.

Answer (score 1):

Use a jquery dialog then you can post or check what every you want from a range of buttons. Much more flexible

[Jquery Modal](http://www.queness.com/post/77/simple-jquery-modal-window-tutorial)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned previously, confirm() is the best bet, however don't forget you can check which button was pressed, and ask for a value at the same time using prompt().

```
if (prompt("Click the OK button?")!=null)
{
alert('you clicked OK and entered a value')
}
else
{
alert('you clicked cancel')
}
```