# Javascript - How can I block my website if cookies are disabled?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, navigator

I would block my website if cookies are disabled using Javascript or JQuery. Haw can I do that?
I know that I can check if cookies are enabled or not using `navigator.cookieEnabled` and I thought to do a script that use an `alert()` to say to the user to enable the cookies in order to be able to use the website and if he click ok I can call recursively my function which check if cookies are enabled and run the alert if not. This is my idea, but I don't know how to write it because it's my first approach to javascript. Can someone give me an advice? It's my idea the best way to implement it?

Comment: *I can check if cookies are enabled or not using `navigator.cookieEnabled`* Actually, that doesn't tell you if cookies are enabled. It tells you if the client has the capability to store cookies, not if that capability is turned on.

Comment: I thought it was useful to tell me if cookies were enabled on the browser or not, so how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know how to know the user clicked the "ok" button on the alert, you can try this:
[Checking OK button is clicked on alert box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10185473/checking-ok-button-is-clicked-on-alert-box?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

If you want to know whether the cookies is enabled and good to use, you can set cookies and read it again. Refer to below link to see how to set, read and check cookies:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp