# Node.js Module for Popups in Jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, jade4j

I have a Application in Node.js with the Template Engine Jade. I need a module to show a message Box or similar, when the user clicks on a submit button, Like "Do you really submit?"

Comment: Is this a desktop app or a browser app?

Comment: Sorry, in the browser app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a browser app, you can easily use the `confirm` function (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm) for usage documentation). See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4952475) for an example of usage in conjunction with `onclick`.

Comment: Ah ok, maybe clarify that in your question (by editing it)? In any case, I've updated my answer for that scenario, please have a look and see if that works for you.

Comment: But when I use for example result = window.confirm("message"); in my main.js, I get the Error "ReferenceError: window is not defined"

Comment: Are you calling `confirm` from the Node.js environment? Because that is not possible - you need to call it from a script that is run by the browser.

Comment: I call it on the serverside in server.js after calling app.post

Comment: Well, that's the cause of the issue, then. You can't call `confirm` without being in a browser environment - you'll need to move that call to code that is run by the browser.

Comment: Isn't there any other module to call it in server.js after calling app.post ?

Comment: The problem is that you can't easily 'remotely' trigger JavaScript in a browser from within the server, that would be quite the security risk. For that you'd need to set up some socket connection, but even then, you'd need to do the actual call in the browser code. But I hardly think that this is within the scope of what the application needs - could you be a bit more specific in your question on the nature of the problem? Why can't the confirm call be placed in the browser code?

Comment: I want a Dialog Form if the user clicks on the following button: button(type="submit") start/ stop #{instance[0]}

Comment: There are a number of ways of doing it (e.g. an `onclick` attribute on the button element). But this does seem like a bit of brushing up on your HTML/JS knowledge would be helpful here, see [this W3C doc](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) for info on using the `onclick` attribute. Once you've grasped the basics of that, have a look at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4952475) for an example of how to apply that in this particular situation.

Comment: But why I get this Error?TypeError: C:\Users\reif006\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CloudServerAdministration\views\mainSiteEdit.jade:50
   48|             form(action="/action", method="post" )
   49|              input(type="hidden" name="server" value=instance[0]) 
 > 50|              button(type="submit" onclick= window.confirm("test         message")) start/ stop #{instance[0]}
               

Cannot read property 'confirm' of undefined

Comment: You need to put 'window.conf....' in quotes, like so: `onclick="window.confirm(\"test message\")"`

Comment: But if I submit the Message, I get the following Error:ReferenceError: window is not defined

Comment: Could you share a bit more code (edit your original post to add it there, with `monospace` formatting)? It is hard to tell where the issue is coming from, just from the bits of code here and there ;)

Comment: It works with onclick="return confirm('testmessage');return false;"