# How to show a pop-up confirmation after clicking button

Tags: php

I'm still a learner on PHP.

I have a button, and it shall run a JavaScript after clicking it, but I want it to show an alert / pop up for users to confirm whether to continue or to abort.

Can I do the function in my PHP file in the button code?

```
<TD style='text-align:left;padding:0;margin:0;'>
    <INPUT type='button' onmouseup="javascript:JS1();" value='JS1'></INPUT>
</TD>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952459/javascript-alert-box-with-confirm-on-button-press

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to make function and use `confirm();`

```
<TD style='text-align:left;padding:0;margin:0;'>
            <INPUT type='button' onmouseup="myFunction();" value='JS1'></INPUT>
        </TD>
```

And

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    confirm("Please confrim");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Writing code is not what is supposed here.

But, still following pseudo code and concepts should work.

Steps:

1. If you are using jQuery, bind the event of click. If you are using core Javscript, use `onclick` attribute.
2. In the `onclick` function, add a `confirmation` popup.
3. `confirm()` returns `true` if user selects `yes`, or else it will return `false`.
4. Now, you have to proceed only if `true` is returned by `confirm()`.

And javascript code:

```
<script>
function JS1() {
 if (confirm('Your confirmation message')) {
  // Write your code of form submit/button click handler.
 }
 else {
  return false;
 }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried bootstrap modal?

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/

I have provided 3 links. I think these might help you a little. Do a research and it won't be very hard. Good luck.

Comment: TQ ! would go through some time

Comment: @NahidShaiket, really appreciate that you are helping other. But, rather than posting urls/links, answers with some explanations are needed here.