# To execute a button onclick action according to the js confirmation

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am new to JS. I want to have a delete button for my tickets in my cart, when I press the button it should ask if I really want to delete the ticket (JS confirm) if the user confirms then call a function to delete the ticket. I am unsure of how to determine if the user confirmed or not.

Comment: `if (confirm("Really delete?")) ...`

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952459/javascript-alert-box-with-confirm-on-button-press

Answer (score 1):

Us onclick method on button as follow

```
    onclick="return confirm(' really want to delete the ticket?')"
```

Comment: It is a really pure JS and really simple solution.. There are plenty others of course..

Comment: so where do I  place my php function call?

Comment: You can do like -
        <a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $ticketid;?>" onclick="return confirm('really want to delete the ticket?')" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"></a>